# Возможно ли решить эту задачу без массива?

Tags: java

По учёбе задали это задание:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я решил его таким образом через массив (код ниже).
Возможно ли решить его, если последовательность будет не в массиве, а просто int a = 123546
?

(На не разрешают переводить числа в массивы или строки)

Благодарю за внимание...

Мой код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class task_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Сколько элементов в последовательности: ");
        int S = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[S];

        for (int i = 0; i < S; ++i) {
            if(i == array.length-1){
                array[i] = 0; //устанавливаем последний элемент = 0
                continue;
            }
            if(i == array.length-2){
                System.out.println("Введите предпоследний элемент: ");
                array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                continue;
            }

            System.out.println("Введите " + (i+1) + "-й элемент: ");
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        int indexOfMax = array.length-1;
        int indexOfMin = array.length-1;
        for (int N = 0; N < array.length; N++) {
            //если N-ый элемент массива < нуля, то indexOfMin = N
            if (array[N] < array[indexOfMin]){
                indexOfMin = N;
            }
            //тоже самое для самого большого элемента массива
            else if (array[N] > array[indexOfMax]){
                indexOfMax = N;
            }
        }

        if(indexOfMin<indexOfMax) {
            System.out.println("Последовательность: "+Arrays.toString(array)+
                    ". Раньше встречается минимальный элемент: "+array[indexOfMin]);
        }
        else if(indexOfMax<indexOfMin) {
            System.out.println("Последовательность: "+Arrays.toString(array)+
                    ". Раньше встречается максимальный элемент: "+array[indexOfMax]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно.  Вам достаточно запоминать значения минимума и максимума и в какой момент они встретились

Comment: Можно. Вводимые числа не нужно запоминать - после ввода в цикле число сразу проверяете на максимум и минимум и если совпало запоминаете позицию. Всё, число больше не нужно, переходим к вводу следующего. А если ввели `0` - выходим из цикла. И вводить нужно по-нормальному - сначала.

Comment: Ваш код не соответствует заданию, так как у вас в постановке задачи не указано число членов последовательности, следует использовать цикл `while`, пока не будет обнаружен 0

Comment: _если последовательность будет не в массиве, а просто int a = 123546_  Здесь нужно будет преобразовать **число а** в последовательность цифр

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример поиска индексов минимума и максимума:

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

int minPos = -1;
int maxPos = -1;

int count = 0;
int n;
while ((n = scan.nextInt()) != 0) {
    if (minPos == -1 || n < min) {
        minPos = count;
        min = n;
    }
    if (maxPos == -1 || n > max) {
        maxPos = count;
        max = n;
    }
    count++;
}
if (count == 0) {
    System.out.println("Входная последовательность пустая.");
} else if (count == 1) {
    System.out.println("Входная последовательность содержит единственный элемент.");
} else if (minPos < maxPos) {
    System.out.printf("Минимум %d встречается раньше, чем максимум %d%n.", min, max);
} else {
    System.out.printf("Максимум %d встречается раньше, чем минимум %d%n.", max, min);
}
```